# Tableau split string and take from x token until the end of tokens

Tags: tableau-api

I have a field of strings and want to take all the "Elements from position x until the end.

For example there is a *"Field Name"* column with the following values:

- /one/two
- /three/three/four
- /five/six

As result I would like to have:

- two
- three/four
- six

I tried with `SPLIT([Field Name], '/', 2)` but then the "*four*" is missing. Is there a way to talk from token 2 until the end of tokens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
RIGHT([Field Name],LEN([Field Name]) - FINDNTH([Field Name],"/",2))
```

This is returning the right part of the string [Field Name] and specifying to keep the last n characters, where n = length of the original string minus the location of the second "/".