# How to find a sub-string of a text in Tableau based on a separator character

Tags: tableau-api

I have a list of URL's in my data. This URL information also include the URL parameters. I want to find out a list of unique url's. I mean

https://root/member_portal/javax.faces.resource/beanvalidation.js.xhtml?ln=js
https://root/member_portal/javax.faces.resource/beanvalidation.js.xhtml?ln=js&v=6.0.0 should be the same. 
Is there a text operation to create a calculated field which will find the substring before the "?" sign in the URL?

Comment: What have you tried so far? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922554/tableau-split-string-and-take-from-x-token-until-the-end-of-tokens/49925578#49925578) would get you pretty close--use a LEFT function instead of RIGHT...

Comment: learn about regular expressions.

Comment: Here's a great write up on string calcs http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2014/06/string-calculations-in-tableau.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tableau split string and take from x token until the end of tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922554/tableau-split-string-and-take-from-x-token-until-the-end-of-tokens)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your parameterised URL data is kept in [URL] field; you may use below formula to strip the main URL part:

```
LEFT([URL],FIND([URL], "?")-1)
```

`FIND` returns the position of "?" character in our URL field data. And `LEFT` returns everything before that index - 1.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. I used this as IF (FIND([Page],"?") > 0) 
THEN Left([Page],FIND([Page],"?"))
ELSE [Page]
END

Comment: Hi, Hakan can you please upvote the question. I have issues related to the number of questions with 0 votes. This problems causes me not entering new questions.

Comment: Hi Ferda, It seems that I have already upvoted your question at the very first time, I guess there also is a downvote so it counts to 0 :(